Water droplets/spray around water softener
I have a full-house water softener fitted near the water main entry point in the house. (Aside from a separate pipe for drinking water, everything else goes through the water softener.) The water softener is located in the garage, with the floor being rubberised tiles over poured concrete.
Lately, I've noticed small amount of water on the floor around the water softener.  This doesn't look like a typical leak.  Rather it looks like sprayed water droplets. Moreover, I had a couple items on the floor next to the water softener - and the water droplets were on top of these items, indicating the source of the water was above the base/floor.
The amount is very small, so I'm not too worried yet, however I want to get this resolved before it becomes a serious problem.
I checked all connections on the pipes and water softener itself - all connections are bone dry. Area around the lid (where the salt is put in) is also dry. The overflow pipe, the drainage pipe - everything - is dry.
I shut off water softener entry/exit valves and opened the pass-through valve - effectively eliminating the water softener from the system altogether. I wiped dry all the water around and left it for a week - no water on the floor.  Returned the water softener into the system - the water reappeared within a couple of days. Thus I am fairly sure the water is coming from the water softener.
Where can it be coming from? What else can/should I check?

Consider to observe the system when the recharge cycle is being executed. You may have to manually activate it, which may put the water source out of use during that period. Our softener recharges at about 0100 hours, not a convenient time to be checking for spray, but if I manually activate the unit, we can't use the well water for a few hours, not certain how long.

Are the drops anywhere near the drain? When I installed my water softener, I didn't have the drain tube far enough down the standpipe, and when it drained it sprayed a bit of water outside of the standpipe. I also had a slow leak (as in 10 drops or so) around where the body of the softener body connected to the control head - just had to tighten it.

@negacao I don't think it's the drain.  My drain pipe is long enough and goes through the outside wall to the outside.

Two possibilities: could be a tiny pinhole in a fitting or the tank, or condensation from a cold surface (tank or line) in humid weather splashing as it drops off. Or not.

I'll need to check/watch the recharge cycle.  I doubt it's a pinhole as the water droplets are all around the unit, not just on one side.
